# How to retrieve a link from source tags in Cheerio/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, cheerio

I would like to attempt to retrieve the first `data-srcset` image `("https://sample.img_1")`, my attempts so far have not worked. I am attempting this in Cheerio.

My latest attempt is as follows
`$(".sample_picture [media = '(max-width: 640px)']")`, this however is outputting nothing.

```html
<picture class="sample_picture">
<source data-srcset="https://sample.img_1" media="(max-width: 640px)">
<source data-srcset="https://sample.img_2" media="(max-width: 1024px)">
<source data-srcset="https://sample.img_2" media="(max-width: 1920px)">

</picture>
```

Comment: I would try simpler selector that is less strict `.sample_picture [media*="640p"]`. if this doesn't work, then maybe you have broken html and source is not inside picture.

Comment: It did not work, but I am 100% the html isn't broken as I can follow the source link

Comment: The sample you've provided is broken or are we to assume a closing `</picture>` tag? When I add that to your snippet, your selector works fine and `$(".sample_picture [media = '(max-width: 640px)']").length` returns 1.The issue maybe elsewhere. Please provide your code.

Comment: @PeterKA I have now edited and added the closing picture tag. I am still unable to extract the image link using the selector you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you have is good. Perhaps you just need to use the `.data()` method to extract the desired url:

```
const img1 = $(".sample_picture [media = '(max-width: 640px)']").data('srcset');
console.log( img1 ); //https://sample.img_1
```

**DEMO**

```js
$(function() {
   const img1 = $(".sample_picture [media = '(max-width: 640px)']").data('srcset');
   console.log( img1 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<picture class="sample_picture">
<source data-srcset="https://sample.img_1" media="(max-width: 640px)">
<source data-srcset="https://sample.img_2" media="(max-width: 1024px)">
<source data-srcset="https://sample.img_2" media="(max-width: 1920px)">

</picture>
```